# Entity Framework Core Does not Create the Migration Automatically

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I wanted to create a table during the Startup with the Entity Framework. I have context in separate project.

**Startup.cs** in method: Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)

```
try
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>().Database.Migrate();

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    throw;
}
```

This Piece of code is not creating the table.

However when i tried to create the migration by 
`dotnet ef migrations add AddTable_CLient -c MyContext`. The table is being created but the

`scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>().Database.Migrate();` doesnot create the table for me. And It shows table has been created already.

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory: IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<VerittyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=ClientManagement;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
             optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));
        return new VerittyContext(builder.Options);

    }
}
```

**MyContext.cs**

```
public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
public DbSet<CompanyContact> CompanyContact { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
    {
        relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyContact>();
 }
```

I wanted the table to be created automatically when the table is being added to Context class. I don't wanted to add the migration manually. Does using the code below is not the way to add the table to Database automatically?

```
using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>().Database.Migrate();
}
```

Please Help.